# How to get the content of a file uploaded with HTML input file using Java?

Tags: java, html, fileinputstream

I am trying to get the content of a file uploaded using a HTML input type=file and store it into a database.

It's been done with JavaScript, but I need to do it with Java specifically(I am using the Apache Wicket library for the project and no JS allowed).

I know that the browser is gonna return a fakepath for security reasons, so how do I access the file content in this case?

My code in short:

```
//code to retrieve path beforehand

FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(path.toString());
byte[] FileBytes = IOUtilstoByteArray(stream);

//code to add to database afterwards
```

When running on server within the Eclipse IDE it works fine since it retrieves the real path, but when in Browser I need a workaround for the "fakepath"

Comment: the browser is going to provide the file content to the webserver, and the webserver will either put it in a temporary location on the server, or in an in-memory buffer.  I don't really understand this "fakepath" stuff you're talking about.  https://mkyong.com/wicket/wicket-file-upload-example/ shows an upload folder within which the uploaded file would be temporarily stored, but that's from 2012 so take it wit ha grain of salt

Comment: My approach was wrong it seems, thanks